# Any Plunderphonics recommendations?

Tags: genre, sample

I recently got into [Plunderphonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plunderphonics) and I'm aware of the works of [John Oswald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Oswald_(composer)), [Negativland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negativland), [The Residents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Residents), [The Avalanches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avalanches), and [Orchid Spangiafora](http://www.orchidspangiafora.com/). As I searched for more, I saw that finding Plunderphonics is incredibly difficult. If you know some unpopular or underrated Plunderphonics artists, albums or tracks, I would like to know. Just a few notes:

- It will be more helpful if you provide links for the music.
- Plunderphonics tracks are usually short, that´s true, but I prefer tracks that last 6 minutes or longer.
- No [vaporwave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaporwave). It's too pop-sounding for me.

Answer (score 1):

[Girl Talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girl_Talk_(musician)) - [*Feed the Animals*](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6B8C641A648C60F0) ([2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feed_the_Animals)) and [Oneohtrix Point Never](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oneohtrix_Point_Never) - [*Replica*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiwi7d0f91Y) ([2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replica_(Oneohtrix_Point_Never_album))) are both classic albums in my opinion.

Comment: Any comment for the downvote?